# How to transpose single column into multiple uneven columns/rows in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have different test dates and times that can be up to about 100 tests each time point. I received the data that was only a single column that consists of thousands of rows, which should have been delivered in a matrix type grid.

I have only copied a sample, which has 6 time points and up to 4 tests each. I need Excel to "recognize" when there is only a date/time in a cell, then copy that cell to the next date/time to paste in a new sheet and column.

Eventually, I was hoping to also have the Title of the test separated from the results. However, if this is not plausible without knowing the name of every test, I can skip it. This is the data I start with:

```
Title

01/02/2010 0:03
Ounces: 10.87
Concentration: 6.89 (L)
Expiration Date: 11/2/2019  5:47:00

01/06/2011 2:06
Ounces: 18.09
Concentration: 10.7 (H)
Expiration Date: 11/2/2019  5:47:00
Other: Resampled

01/06/2011 2:06
Ounces: 12.87
Concentration: 10.9 (H)
Expiration Date: 11/2/2019  5:47:00
Other: 2nd Sample

09/15/2012 7:07
Ounces: 8.53
Concentration: 9.72
Expiration Date: 12/5/2019  4:45:00

05/02/2013 15:52
Ounces: 11.62
Concentration: 8.42

05/09/2017 1:45
Ounces: 9.34
Concentration: 8.98
```

I created the following Excel VBA, but am still new at programming, especially loops within loops, so I could not figure out how to create the offset that is dynamic enough to both select the right cells, but to copy them over to a new column. I also have redundancy within the code.

```
Sub Transpose()

    Dim dDate As Date
    Dim NumberofTasks As Long
    Dim x As Long

    sSheet = ActiveSheet.Name
    Sheets.Add
    dSheet = ActiveSheet.Name

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        ' All Data is in Column A
        NumberofTasks = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For x = 1 To NumberofTasks
            Sheets(sSheet).Activate
            If IsDate(.Range("A" & x).Value) Then '<-- check if current cell at Column A is Date
                Range(Cells(x, 1), Cells(x, 1).Offset(4, 0)).Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets(dSheet).Activate
                Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
                , Transpose:=True
                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
            End If
        Next x

    End With

End Sub
```

This is what I hoped would happen (but on a much larger scale):
[image]

However, the offset places another date in another cell with the current code. Thank you for any help you can provide me.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to skin a cat. Here is one way using arrays which is much much faster than looping through the range

**Worksheet:**

I am for the sake of coding, assuming that the data is in `Sheet1` and looks like below

[image]

**Logic:**

1. Store the data from the worksheet in an array; Let's call it `InputArray`
2. Create an output array for storing data; Let's call it `OutputArray`
3. Loop through `InputArray` and find the date and then find the rest of the records. store in `OutputArray`
4. direct the output from `OutputArray` to the relevant worksheet.

**Code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim InputArray As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim recCount As Long
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim OutputArray() As String

    '~~> Set relevant input sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        '~~> Find Last Row in Col A
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Store col A in array
        InputArray = .Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value

        '~~> Find Total number of records
        For i = LBound(InputArray) To UBound(InputArray)
            If IsDate(InputArray(i, 1)) Then recCount = recCount + 1
        Next i

        '~~> Create an array for output
        ReDim OutputArray(1 To 5, 1 To recCount + 1)

        recCount = 2

        '~~> Fill Col A of output array
        OutputArray(1, 1) = "Title"
        OutputArray(2, 1) = "Ounces"
        OutputArray(3, 1) = "Concentration"
        OutputArray(4, 1) = "Expiration Date"
        OutputArray(5, 1) = "Other"

        '~~> Loop through input array
        For i = UBound(InputArray) To LBound(InputArray) Step -1
            If IsDate(InputArray(i, 1)) Then '< Check if date
                OutputArray(1, recCount) = InputArray(i, 1)

                '~~> Check for Ounces and store in array
                If i + 1 < UBound(InputArray) + 1 Then _
                If UCase(Left(Trim(InputArray(i + 1, 1)), 2)) = "OU" _
                Then OutputArray(2, recCount) = Trim(Replace(InputArray(i + 1, 1), "Ounces:", ""))

                '~~> Check for Concentration and store in array
                If i + 2 < UBound(InputArray) + 1 Then _
                If UCase(Left(Trim(InputArray(i + 2, 1)), 2)) = "CO" _
                Then OutputArray(3, recCount) = Trim(Replace(InputArray(i + 2, 1), "Concentration:", ""))

                '~~> Check for Expiration Date and store in array
                If i + 3 < UBound(InputArray) + 1 Then _
                If UCase(Left(Trim(InputArray(i + 3, 1)), 2)) = "EX" _
                Then OutputArray(4, recCount) = Trim(Replace(InputArray(i + 3, 1), "Expiration Date:", ""))

                '~~> Check for Other and store in array
                If i + 4 < UBound(InputArray) + 1 Then _
                If UCase(Left(Trim(InputArray(i + 4, 1)), 2)) = "OT" _
                Then OutputArray(5, recCount) = Trim(Replace(InputArray(i + 4, 1), "Other:", ""))

                recCount = recCount + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    '~~> Output it to relevant sheet
    Sheet2.Range("A1").Resize(5, recCount - 1).Value = OutputArray
End Sub
```

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score -1):

May try something like this. Original code was modified and organized to complete the task intended. It takes cares if the other parameters of the test result are not organised in sequence as shown, blank row in between the parameters, no blank row between test results and or missing parameters. It only considers parameters found between rows of two test titles (date time). Takes only 0.5 seconds to process 200 test results from more than 1 K rows.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Transpose()
Dim dDate As Date
Dim NumberofTasks As Long
Dim x As Long, LastRow As Long, Xval As Variant
Dim srcWs As Worksheet, trgWs As Worksheet
Dim tm As Double
tm = Timer
Set srcWs = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set trgWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
trgWs.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Title"
trgWs.Cells(2, 1).Value = "Ounces:"
trgWs.Cells(3, 1).Value = "Concentration:"
trgWs.Cells(4, 1).Value = "Expiration Date:"
trgWs.Cells(5, 1).Value = "Other:"

With srcWs
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    NumberofTasks = 0
    x = 1
    Do While x <= LastRow
    Xval = .Cells(x, 1).Value
        If IsDate(Xval) Then
        NumberofTasks = NumberofTasks + 1
        trgWs.Cells(1, NumberofTasks + 1).Value = .Range("A" & x).Value
        ElseIf VarType(Xval) = vbString And NumberofTasks > 0 Then
        Xval = Trim(LCase(Xval))
           If InStr(1, Xval, "ounces:") > 0 Then
           trgWs.Cells(2, NumberofTasks + 1).Value = Trim(Replace(Xval, "ounces:", ""))
           ElseIf InStr(1, Xval, "concentration:") > 0 Then
           trgWs.Cells(3, NumberofTasks + 1).Value = Trim(Replace(Xval, "concentration:", ""))
           ElseIf InStr(1, Xval, "expiration date:")  > 0 Then
           trgWs.Cells(4, NumberofTasks + 1).Value = Trim(Replace(Xval, "expiration date:", ""))
           ElseIf InStr(1, Xval, "other:")  > 0 Then
           trgWs.Cells(5, NumberofTasks + 1).Value = Trim(Replace(Xval, "other:", ""))
           End If
        End If
    x = x + 1
    Loop
End With
'Debug.Print "Seconds "; Timer - tm
End Sub
```

Tested to produce the result like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWbjY.png)

Answer (score -1):

**I think here is better way to do it using `Range.Find`**

- Assuming the Data is in 1st Column of `Sheet1` ie. Column `A`
- In Demo the Expiration Date is not right, I have corrected that in the Code.

**Try this  code:**

```
Sub TP()

Dim wk As Worksheet: Set wk = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long: lr = wk.Cells(wk.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
j = 4
For i = 3 To lr

    Set rng = wk.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 1).End(xlDown))
        wk.Cells(2, j).Value = rng.Cells(1, 1).Value

    Set fnd = rng.Find("Ounces")
        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then wk.Cells(3, j).Value = Split(fnd.Value, ":")(1)
        Set fnd = Nothing
    Set fnd = rng.Find("Concentration")
        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then wk.Cells(4, j).Value = Split(fnd.Value, ":")(1)
        Set fnd = Nothing
    Set fnd = rng.Find("Expiration")
        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then wk.Cells(5, j).Value = Right(fnd.Value, Len(fnd.Value) - Len(Split(fnd.Value, ":")(0)) - 2)
        Set fnd = Nothing
    Set fnd = rng.Find("Other")
        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then wk.Cells(6, j).Value = Split(fnd.Value, ":")(1)
        Set fnd = Nothing

    i = Cells(i, 1).End(xlDown).row + 1
    j = j + 1
Next

End Sub
```

---

**Demo:**

[image]